# Table Query Selecting one field from multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am trying to write a query that will select the records from multiple tables whose field pass or fail = fail. Normally I wouldn't have a problem writing this its pretty straight forward. My problem is that I normalized the data of the fields. The field I am trying to select is called PassOrFail, however since it occurs in multiple tables I normalized the field and changed it to "Tablename"PassOrFail i.e OvenPassOrFail. My question is how do I select this field for all the tables that have this field? How would I type the WHERE and FROM expressions. Would I look something like this?

```
   SELECT*
   FROM   Oven, FirstPunch
   WHERE  Oven.OvenPassOrFail,FirstPunch.FirstPPassOrFail = "Fail";
```

Or would I have to undo the normalization of the fields to get it to work? Any tips or suggestions to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to write separate queries for each table and then UNION them together. Check out documentation on UNION. You should be able to find a list of all tables that have that column by querying the system tables.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, All I had to do was add an AND statement and it worked.

```
SELECT *
FROM Oven, FirstPunch
WHERE OvenPassOrFail = "Fail" AND FirstPPassOrFail = "Fail";
```

Comment: should you use OR instead of AND?

Comment: @PeterMourfield that is a good point, say if one table doesn't have any "Fails" in programming logic the AND statement would mean that since its false then the whole statement is false even if there are "Fail"s in the next table. Thanks for the insight